# Apache Derby error

Tags: derby

Hey i am trying to teach myself how to use JDBC using Apache Derby.  And in a tutorial it says:
Compile sample application

Compile the sample application as shown below:

javac SimpleApp.java

You can safely ignore any compile warnings that might pop up.
Run sample application

Run the sample application like this:

java SimpleApp

So i open up my command prompt and type this in and im getting an error:
Error: Could not find or load SimpleApp.java

Does anyone know what im doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting the error on the 'javac' command or on the 'java' command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you supposed to type in the example or download a sample? If so, you'll need to put that file in a directory on your hard drive and cd to that directory before compiling it if the Java file is not in a package.

If it is in a package, then you'll need to create a directory structure that mirrors the package structure before compiling.